# Installation of data card

Tags: system-installation, internet, devices

I am unable to use my data card. How can I use it. Basically I am using a data card which has auto installer option for which whenever I plug it on any device it installs automatically. But in ubuntu it's not responding properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo eject /dev/sr0
```

or

```
sudo eject /dev/sr1
```

I have this issue with my USB Nokia CS-15 Data stick.  It mounts as a CD drive, and until you "eject" the CD drive, it will not see the Data stick.

If your CD rom opens when you use SR0, then your card is most likely SR1.

Answer (score 0):

Your data card should show up a usually within a minute of plugging in. Follow the following steps:

1. Click the `network manager` icon and you should see `Mobile Broadband`.
2. Once you see that, it means that your data card has been detected. Click `Edit Connections`.
3. In the `Network Connections` dialog, click on the `+` button to add a new connection.
4. Choose your `Connection type` as `Mobile Broadband`.
5. Click next and choose your `country`.
6. Click next and choose your `operator`.

Finish and you should see your connection in Network Manager. Click on it to connect to the network.